# Manually change hour of 'dttm' object in R for entire dataframe column

Tags: r, date, datetime

Is there a simple way to change the hour for all time entries in a dttm column in R to the same value (e.g., 11:00 A.M.)?

For example, given the dttm 2020-01-01 00:00:00, can I change this automatically to 2020-01-01 11:00:00?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need `lubridate::hour(df1$datetime) <- 11`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to assign only the `hour` part to a specific value

```
library(lubridate)
hour(df1$datetime) <- 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two base R options.

1. Change the date-time to `POSIXlt` format and change the hour component from it.

```
df$a <- as.POSIXlt(df$a)
df$a$hour <- 11
df

#                     a
#1  2021-08-21 11:17:08
#2  2021-08-21 11:16:59
#3  2021-08-21 11:17:06
#4  2021-08-21 11:17:04
#5  2021-08-21 11:17:01
#6  2021-08-21 11:17:07
#7  2021-08-21 11:17:05
#8  2021-08-21 11:17:02
#9  2021-08-21 11:17:00
#10 2021-08-21 11:17:03
```

2. Use regex to change the hour to 11 and change the time to `POSIXct` again.

```
df$a <- as.POSIXct(sub('\\s(\\d+)', ' 11', df$a), tz = 'UTC')
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = Sys.time() + sample(10))
```